# how to reset password by using html template in django djoser

Tags: django, authentication, http-status-code-405, reset-password, djoser

I created classed based view rest api. where I used django djoser. My activation template and all links are worked. but now I am working on reset password where I used template for rest password. but **giving 405 error.**
**I was getting reset password link. also my html page is working but when I changed my password and hit on submit its giving me 405 error**

views.py

```
class ResetPasswordView(View):
      def get (self, request, uid, token):
        return render(request, 'password_reset_email.html') # display activation page when user click on link which recieved fron gmail

    def post (self, request,uid,token):
        print('In Password Reset Post')
        new_password=request.post.get("new_password")
        print("new_password :",new_password)
        re_new_password=request.post.get("re_new_password")
        print("re_new_password : ",re_new_password)
        payload = json.dump({'uid': uid, 'token': token, 'new_password': new_password, 're_new_password': re_new_password})
        protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'  # will evaluate to True if the connection is secure (HTTPS: HTTP over TLS) or False if non-secure (standard HTTP).
        web_url = protocol + request.get_host() + '/'
        password_reset_url = "users/reset_password_confirm/" # url used for activate user
        password_post_url = web_url + AUTHENTICATION_BASE_ROUTE + password_reset_url # for activate user
        print('url : ', password_post_url)
        response = request.post(password_post_url,data=payload)
        return HttpResponse(response.text)
```

urls.py

```
    re_path(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uid>[\w-]+)/(?P<token>[\w-]+)/$', ResetPasswordView.as_view()),
```

password_reset_email.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      {{ form.as_p}}
                      <div class="container">
                        <h1>Register</h1>
                        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
                        <hr>
                        <label for="psw"><b>New Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="new_password" id="new_password" required>

                        <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="re_new_password" id="re_new_password"
                          required>
                        <hr>

                        <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
                      </div>

                    </form>
```

settings.py

```
DJOSER = {
# 'activation': 'user_profile.email.ActivationEmail',
'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
'EMAIL':
{
    'activation': 'user_profile.email.ActivationEmail',
    'conformation_email':'user_profile.email.ConfirmationEmail',
    'password_reset_email':'user_profile.email.PasswordResetEmail',
    'PasswordChangedConfirmationEmail':'user_profile.email.PasswordChangedConfirmationEmail'

},
'SERIALIZERS': {
    'user_create': 'user_profile.serializer.UserSerializer',
    'user': 'user_profile.serializer.UserSerializer',
}
```

}

```
AUTHENTICATION_BASE_ROUTE = 'authentication/v2/'
```

**I was getting reset password link. also my html page is working but when I changed my password and hit on submit its giving me 405 error**

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change json.dump to json.dumps
2. Try requests.post. You can import requests into your terminal to see feedback without always refreshing the page
3. Consider adding more error handling (password validation, host_site, submit response code)

Short Answer:

```
import json 
import requests

payload = json.dumps({
                'uid': kwargs.get('uid'),
                'token': kwargs.get('token'),
                'new_password': password,
                're_new_password': password_confirmation,
            })

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers = headers)
```

Long Answer:

I found it worked best for me using this type of view.

```
    @api_view(('GET', 'POST'))
    @renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
    @permission_classes([AllowAny])
    def reset_user_password(request, **kwargs):
    # Uses djoser to reset password
    if request.POST:
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        password_confirmation = request.POST.get('password_confirmation')
```

I also added some password validation upon submit. I believe the code could be avoided by simply using a Django form (which would validate inside the page instead of upon submit) but I didn't feel it was necessary for this purpose.

```
        
        # Will eventually switch to a form that can process this information live
        if password.isdigit() or len(password)<8:
            message = "Your password must contain at least 8 characters and cannot be entirely numeric."
            return render(request, 'core/password/reset_password.html', {'message': message})
        elif password.isdigit():
            message = "Your password cannot be entirely numeric."
            return render(request, 'core/password/reset_password.html', {'message': message})
        elif len(password)<8 or len(password_confirmation)<8:
            message = "Your password is too short, it must contain at least 8 characters."
            return render(request, 'core/password/reset_password.html', {'message': message})
        elif password != password_confirmation:
            message = "The passwords you have entered do not match. Please re-enter and try again."
            return render(request, 'core/password/reset_password.html', {'message': message})
```

Now formatting the data...

```
        else: 

            # Data to accept -> the uid and token is obtained as keyword arguments in the url
            payload = json.dumps({
                'uid': kwargs.get('uid'),
                'token': kwargs.get('token'),
                'new_password': password,
                're_new_password': password_confirmation,
            })

            # PROTOCOL
            protocol = 'https'
            if bool(request) and not request.is_secure():
                protocol = 'http'
```

IMPORTANT NOTE FOR DOCKER PEOPLE -> if you use Docker to host your site

I was able to post to my Docker using postman or simply the terminal, but it was not working in my code. After HOURS of suffering, it turns out that I was posting to the wrong port. External port was 5000 and external port was 5090.

```
            # - - -- URLS -- - - 
            # Current Site -> needs to be adjusted depending on the docker 
            hosted_site = request.get_host()
            docker_site = '0.0.0.0:5000'

            # Endpoint
            djoser_password_reset_url = 'auth/users/reset_password_confirm/'


            # COMPLETE URL
            if hosted_site == '0.0.0.0:5090':
                url = '{0}://{1}/{2}'.format(protocol, docker_site, djoser_password_reset_url)
            else:
                url = '{0}://{1}/{2}'.format(protocol, hosted_site, djoser_password_reset_url)

            # HEADERS
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

            
            response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers = headers)

            # Verifying the request sent - server returns 204 (no content)
            if response.status_code == 204:
                messages.success(request, 'Your password has been reset successfully!')
```

I also created a success page to reroute them to once the request has been successfully sent. Using reverse allows the site to correctly redirect. Otherwise it will append the redirect url to the current site url.

```
               # Redirect to success, your password has been reset
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reset-password-confirm'))
               # Error handling if the response code is not 204
                else:
                response_object = response.json()
                response_object_keys = response_object.keys()
                for key in response_object_keys:
                    decoded_string = response_object.get(key)[0].replace("'", "\'")
                    messages.error(request, f'{decoded_string}')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    else:

      # If the request is GET 
      return render(request, '[your app here]/password/reset_password.html')
```